# Alias syntax for Firefox 'cfx run -profile <dir>'

Tags: powershell, firefox-addon, alias

I would like to know how to do set-alias in PowerShell for the cmd used in developing Firefox extension:

```
cfx run -p C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ripltbxm.cfxp
```

I've added the following to Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:

```
Set-Alias cfxp cfx run -p "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ripltbxm.cfxp"
```

But when PowerShell is launched, it shows the error:

```
Set-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'run'.
At D:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:2 char:1
+ Set-Alias cfxp cfx run -p "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand
```

Also tried:

```
Set-Alias cfxp "cfx run -p C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ripltbxm.cfxp"
```

with another error:

```
cfxp : The term 'cfx run -p C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ripltbxm.cfxp' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cfxp
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cfx run -p C:\U...s\ripltbxm.cfxp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell aliases can be defined only for commands or cmdlets, not for entire commandlines with parameters:

```
NAME
    New-Alias

SYNOPSIS
    Creates a new alias.
[...]
DESCRIPTION
    The New-Alias cmdlet creates a new alias in the current Windows
    PowerShell session. Aliases created by using New-Alias are not
    saved after you exit the session or close Windows PowerShell. You
    can use the Export-Alias cmdlet to save your alias information to
    a file. You can later use Import-Alias to retrieve that saved
    alias information.

PARAMETERS
[...]
    -Value <String>
        Specifies the name of the cmdlet or command element that is
        being aliased.
```

You'll need a custom function if you want a shorthand for running a particular command with parameters.

```psh
function cfxp {
  & cfx run -p "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ripltbxm.cfxp"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! I've stumbled upon similar answers on stackoverflow but forgive me that I did not realize those were applicable to my situation.

Comment: May I ask what does the '& ' before 'cfx run' do because the alias still works without it?

Comment: @James_ It's PowerShell's call operator. It's optional when using bare words, but required if your command name is a string (e.g. `$cmd = 'cfx'; & $cmd ...` or `& 'C:\path with spaces\cfx' ...`).